# How do I break out of the 'foreach' loop?

Tags: r

You'd think that would be well documented and easy to find, but I don't see anything about flow control in the 'foreach' manual.

Comment: http://old.doctyper.com/archives/200807/breaking-out-of-a-foreach-loop/, which suggests throwing an error and catching it outside the loop.  Ugly, but it will work if you have no other option.

Comment: That's incredibly ugly and inconvenient.  For starters, the (largish) loop probably needs to be wrapped inside a function, or else the whole piece of code becomes completely unreadable :(